# The Salmon Life Cycle

Tags: grammar

[The title of this article is The Salmon Life Cycle.](https://www.nps.gov/olym/learn/nature/the-salmon-life-cycle.htm) It must be correct since it's a government site. But why am I thinking the title is not good. Is "the" with "salmon" or "life cycle". Would it be better to say The Salmon's Life Cycle?

Comment: "It must be correct since it's a government site. "  Absolutely, because governments never make mistakes of any sort (irony!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* say 'The Salmon's Life Cycle' and that would be perfectly correct as well.

Remember that 'salmon' is both the singular, and the plural. It can refer to one, many, or the fish *as a kind*. So the original quote is perfectly correct, just as there would be nothing wrong with saying 'the *human* life cycle'.

Comment: Or even 'The Life Cycle of the Salmon'.